# Spacy script running on terminal but throws import error when executed via PHP

Tags: php, python, shell, spacy

I am running a Shell script from PHP via

```
shell_exec("path/to/script path/to/argument");
```

The same script when executed via terminal, runs perfectly but when executed via PHP it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/file1.py", line 9, in <module>
    import spacy
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .deprecated import resolve_model_name
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/deprecated.py", line 8, in <module>
from .cli import download
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .download import download
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 9, in <module>
from .link import link_package
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 4, in <module>
import pip
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip.index import Link
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

In the above code /home/file1.py is executed in the shell script somewhere.

So basically I think that spacy is not found by python when executed via PHP but is found when executed via terminal.
Kindly suggest a way in which I can solve the problem.

**UPDATE**

So I tried looking for where Spacy is installed and on the [official website](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/#tests), I found that the path can be found by running the following command in terminal.

```
python -c "import os; import spacy; print(os.path.dirname(spacy.__file__))"
```

So I did this and on the terminal I got this output :

```
/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy
```

But when I executed the same via PHP using

```
echo shell_exec('python3.5 -c "import os; import spacy; print(os.path.dirname(spacy.__file__))" 2>&1');
```

I got this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 5, in
from .deprecated import resolve_model_name
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/deprecated.py", line 8, in
from .cli import download
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in
from .download import download
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 9, in
from .link import link_package
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 4, in
import pip
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar # noqa
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in
from pip.index import Link
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in
from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in
from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

Comment: install the required libraries

Comment: I have installed the libraries and it is running on the terminal. So I dont think there is a problem with the libraries. I guess the problem is with the path to libraries via PHP.

Comment: Can you add the both commands in your question which runs and which is throwing exception?

Comment: @DileepKumar my PHP code is executing a bash script, which calls a python script in pipeline, which has the line `import spacy` and the error is thrown from that line as evident from the traceback.
On Terminal, I execute `path/to/script path/to/argument` directly and its giving the desired output.

Comment: try command like shell_exec("cd path/to/script; ./file1.py path/to/argument")

Comment: Actually its a pipeline so cannot execute that file separately.

Comment: In terminal, what's your output for `which python3.5`? And in php, what's the output for `echo shell_exec('which python3.5')`